# Text to zip Java. Is there a way? Text on a webpage to .zip

Tags: java, text, zip, converters

I have a question related to Java and Zip-files. 
Is there a way to make this into a .zip - file?
I have a webpage where the text pops up (if you have the right log-in criterias), and how do you make that into a .zip format? (Because there is correct file-structur there)

The text is here:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/s/il24ih0fu4h7iqn/client.txt
It does **NOT** show up as a .txt, thats just me adding it for you (easier readability)
```

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to create zip files in Java?

Comment: You would zip it, basically... what code have you tried, and what happened? The fact that it's a text file is irrelevant.

Comment: Do u want to add client.txt to client.zip or just rename client.txt to client.zip

Comment: Hi! Thanks for commenting! Uhm... there is no .txt file exactly.

There is just the text showing up on a web-page, and (it's a schools task) I'm supposed to get it back into a .zip

Comment: See my answer below.  Instead of using a text file as an argument, modify it to take a List of strings.  For each string in the list write a line to the zip file.  So you would replace the loop using in.readLine() with a for each loop of the List of strings.  Get it?

Comment: @OleReidarHolm - No problem.  Please accept my answer if it helps.  I can show you a modification as I described if you are having trouble, but just show me where you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html

```
 public static boolean zipFile(final File fileToZip, final File zippedFile) {
            boolean successStatus = false;
            BufferedReader in = null;
            ZipOutputStream out = null;

        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(
                    fileToZip), "UTF-8"));
            out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zippedFile));
            out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileToZip.getName()));
            String line;
            final byte[] newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator")
                    .getBytes("UTF-8");

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                final byte[] buffer = line.getBytes("UTF-8");
                out.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                out.write(newLine, 0, newLine.length);
            }

            out.closeEntry();
            out.finish();
            successStatus = true;
        } catch (final IOException ex) {
            successStatus = false;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                    in = null;
                }
            } catch (final IOException ex) {

            }
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                    out = null;
                }
            } catch (final IOException ex) {

            }
        }
        return successStatus;
    }
```